# Can these two sets be equipotent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Equipotent: $A$ is equipotent to $B$ if $A$ bijective to $B$

Bijective: $A$ is bijective to $B$ if $A$ is injective and surjective

$|X| = 10 $

$A = \{Y \subseteq X | \text{$Y$ has $7$ elements}\}$

$B = \{Z \subseteq X | \text{$Z$ has $3$ elements}\}$

Show that $A \approx B$

Now, can this be equipotent?

if $X=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}  $

$Y=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\} $

$Z=\{7,8,9\}$

As fas as I know this two sets have diferent number of elements, so it will be $A$ being only surjective to $B$, but not injective

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: You're misinterpreting $A$ as $Y$ and $B$ as $Z$. In fact, $A$ and $B$ are sets of sets.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the given data: neither $\;A\;$ nor $\;B\;$ are **one set with** $\;7,\,3\;$ elements, resp., but $\;A\;$ is the *set of all sets with* $\;7\;$ elements from $\;X\;$ , and $\;B\;$ is the set of all subsets with $\;3\;$ elements from $\;X\;$ ...

Comment: X={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}  
A={(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),(0,1,2,3,4,5,7)...}  
B={(0,1,2),(0,1,3)...}  
Something like this?

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is the set containing all $7$-element subsets of $X$, while $B$ is the set containing all $3$-element subsets of $X$.

A bijection from $A$ to $B$ would involve the complement with respect to $X$.